# Python3 argparse nargs="+" get number of arguments

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I'm now googling for quite a while and I just don't find any solution to my problem.

I am using argparse to parse some command line arguments. I want to be able to parse an arbitrary number of arguments > 1 (therefore nargs="+") and I want to know afterwards how many arguments I have parsed. The arguments are all strings. But I get a problem when I just have one argument, because then the length of the list is the number of characters of the word and not 1 as in 1 argument. And I want to know how many arguments were parsed. Does anyone know how I could solve this problem?

examples:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--test", type=str, nargs="+", required=False, default="hi")
args = parser.parse_args()
test = args.test

print(test)
print(len(test))
```

So with `python3 example.py --test hello hallo hey` the output is:

```
['hello', 'hallo', 'hey']
3
```

But with `python3 example.py --test servus` the output is:

```
servus
6
```

What I already know is that I could do `print([test])` but I only want to do that if I have 1 argument. Because if I have more than one arguments and use `print([test])` I get a double array... So I just want to know the number of parsed arguments for "test".

I cannot imagine that I am the only one with such a problem, but I could not find anything in the internet. Is there a quick and clean solution?

Comment: I'd expect `args.test` to be `['servus']` a list of length 1.  I'll verify  that later.  With that testing you might want to change the default to a list.

Comment: yes, sorry forgot that (just here, not in my actual code)! I will try out your suggested answer tomorrow and report back :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left off the `test=args.test` line.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--test", type=str, nargs="+", required=False, default="hi")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
print(len(args.test))
```

test cases

```
0856:~/mypy$ python3 stack68020846.py --test one two three
Namespace(test=['one', 'two', 'three'])
3
0856:~/mypy$ python3 stack68020846.py --test one
Namespace(test=['one'])
1
0856:~/mypy$ python3 stack68020846.py 
Namespace(test='hi')
2
```

change the default to `default=[]`

```
0856:~/mypy$ python3 stack68020846.py 
Namespace(test=[])
0
```

Comment: Perfect! It works now! I changed the default to ```default=['hi']``` and now it works perfectly fine! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Theres probably a better solution, but try this:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--test", type=str, nargs="+", required=False, default="hi")
args = parser.parse_args()

print("Number of arguments:", len(args._get_kwargs()[-1][-1]))
```

By the way, i figured this out by checking the content of args with `print(dir(args))`

Comment: He probably left out a `test=args.test` line.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (in case someone, for some reason, needs the `default` not to be a list): you could first check if the argument is a list, then get `len` if it is. For example:

```py
if type(test) == list:
    print(len(test))
```